# How to remove "form_key" in magento2

Tags: magento2, extensions, stores, form-key

How can I remove "form_key" globally in my magento2 store?

Comment: why you want to remove form key as it will compromise security?

Comment: Form keys are a means of preventing against cross site request forgery

Comment: I'm using cashfree extension for payment gateway. when the user goes to payment gateway page. the form is submitted with  "form_key". which the API is not expecting. and it is throwing an error only because of "form_key". i cannot edit the code of the extension. so i have to remove the "form_key". please help me with removing "form_key"